# How to open excel 2007/2010 on browser by using .ashx?

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I have already created a ashx file to open excel 2007 on website.

Here is the code in test.aspx: (call test.htm to open a popup)

```
    <a href="test.htm" target="_blank">Export</a>
```

Here is the code in test.htm: (using iframe to load the excel file)

```
<iframe src="handler1.ashx" style="height: 421px; width: 800px" ></iframe>
```

Here are the code in handle.ashx:

```
    void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        string filePath = "E:/test.xlsx";
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=test.xlsx");
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

but the excel file is always opened by Microsoft Excel Application. 
Please help me.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

context.Response.WriteFile(filePath); // you are trying to write out into a file block.

before that you need to fetch all data into a memory. change to like this

```
context.Response.Write(YourExcelData);
```

Comment: hi Ravi,
I tried to edit code as below, but it has error (cannot open ebcause file format or file ext is not valid) when opening file:
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
            fs.Read(b, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            fs.Close();
            context.Response.Write(b);